# Conditional vs. nonconditional variational family

Tags: autoencoders, variational-bayes, approximate-inference

In variational bayes, distributions in the variational family $\mathcal{Q}$ are denoted $q_\phi$ and are used to approximate the posterior $p_\theta(z|x)$. However, I've seen both notations $q_\phi(z|x)$ and $q_\phi(z)$. What's the difference and how are they each used?

My interpretation was that $q_\phi(z)$ and $q_\phi(z|x)$ are a prior and posterior on $\mathcal{Q}$. Is this the right interpretation? It doesn't make sense that we should need a prior for $q_\phi$ since it is being optimized as an approximation to $p_\theta(z|x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My interpretation was that $q_{\phi}()$ and $q_{\phi}\left(z | x \right)$ are a prior and posterior on $\mathcal{Q}$" **is not correct at all**. $\mathcal{Q}$ is the variational family defining the distribution space. $q_{\phi}()$ and $q_{\phi}\left(z | x \right)$ live in  $\mathcal{Q}$ and used to approximate the prior/posterior defined for a data distribution.

Both notations are used actually. $q_{\phi}()$ actually stems from the ELBO derivation(You can check these [lecture notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eepxing/Class/10708-15/notes/10708_scribe_lecture13.pdf) from CMU), i.e. the KL divergence definition.

For VAE's, we specifically denote $q_{\phi}\left(z | x \right)$ because the encoder tries to learn an **amortized posterior distribution**, which instead of optimizing a set of free parameters unlike in the lecture notes that I've shared sbove, we can propose **parameterized function(like a neural network)** that maps from observation space to the parameters of the approximate posterior distribution.

In fact, there are advanced VI techniques that allow implicit priors for VAE's like [Semi-Implicit Variational Inference (SIVI)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11183).

TL;DR, try to stick with $q_{\phi}\left(z | x \right)$ for VAE posteriors and always make sure to understand which distribution you are trying to approximate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! So why is amortized inference called that? Is it the fact that we aren't computing $q_\phi(z_i)$ for each individual datapoint but rather defining a global function and then letting each datapoint contribute? ($\leftarrow$ is this right?)

Comment: Ah I did some reading online, will edit your answer for my own reference if that's okay with you

Comment: @900edges There's nothing wrong with writing your own answer to the question.

Comment: @Sycorax I want to accept their answer, just wanted to fill out a detail!

Answer (score 1):

Note: the point of Amortized VI is this:

Traditional VI defines the latent variable $z_i$ for each individual observation, and then optimizes them all jointly. This is computationally expensive to have to re-run the inference procedure for every datapoint. Instead, one can define a parameterized function, i.e. $q_\phi(z|x)$ sending $x \rightarrow z$. Now the parameters to update are the parameters of the function rather than the distributions of every $z_i$. For a new observation, we only have to pass it through the network rather than update everything.

Comment: Good follow-up. Thank you @900edges